# Java thread that upserts document in Couchbase is stuck in Waiting state indefinitely

Tags: java, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

Spring Boot Version: 2.3.1.RELEASE
Spring Data Couchbase: 4.3.5
Couchbase Java Client: 3.2.7
My spring boot application is getting stuck after inserting a document in Couchbase. (I can see document was inserted successfully)

```
` final CatalogLock entity = lockRepository.save(lock);
        return entity.getId();

public interface CatalogLockRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<CatalogLock, String>`
```

"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x0000000003614800 nid=0x5f14 waiting on condition [0x000000000360b000]
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
- parking to wait for  <0x0000000709cf3808> (a java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch$Sync)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:836)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:997)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:231)
at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:87)
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1679)
at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.ExecutableUpsertByIdOperationSupport$ExecutableUpsertByIdSupport.one(ExecutableUpsertByIdOperationSupport.java:75)

There seems to be a similar issue raised in Couchbase forum https://forums.couchbase.com/t/java-thread-that-queries-couchbase-stuck-in-waiting-state/24144
but with no response

Tried different versions of Couchbase java client and spring data couchbase, reactore-core. Nothing helped

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue that is fixed in Spring Boot 2.6.6.